# My CV got sent to my current job and we are not currently recruiting

Tags: resume, recruitment, legal

My CV was sent to my current job by a recruitment consultant who has a long standing relationship with my boss for about 20 years, without my consent. This has led to my boss being hostile towards me ever since the recruiter whom wasn't the person in contact with me got hold of my CV from her workplace.

Can i file a legal action in regards to this against the agency as this is definitely a breach of confidentiality.

Comment: This is not the place for legal advice. However, if you know that the agency sent your CV to the present job, and you were not seeking a new job (or did you? that changes everything), can't you just explain this to your boss?

Comment: Important information missing: Are you actually looking for a job?

Comment: How did your CV end up at the recruiter's workplace? You sent it there, presumably. It certainly seems bad practice for a recruiter to send a CV on spec to a company which is not recruiting, and to send a CV to someone's current employer (if that's mentioned on the CV). Workplace.SE is not the place for legal advice, but might give advice on how to handle (a) the new work dynamic with your manager; (b) your relationship with the recruitment firm. But that means we need information about your relationship with the recruitment firm.

Comment: Did you get a signed confidentiality agreement from the company?  Did you tell them it was ok to send your resume to prospective employers?

Answer (score 7):

I'd walk up to her/his office and discuss the matter with **extreme clarity and honesty** and without fear of losing the job. I'd talk about my concerns about what I'm feeling after what happened and explain that I was not looking for a job recently (if that's true) and the recruiter did it on its own without my knowledge.

And at the end, I'd explicitly ask if I could address the issue and if we're good. If the answer is yes, even implicitly, then I'd monitor his/her behavior for few days and decide if I actually need to look for a new job.

I'd also contact the recruiter and explain to him/her the trouble that s/he has caused me. And I ask if s/he's willing to make things right?

I don't know which country you're living in, but I'm pretty sure finding a new job is much easier than suing a company. It's also cheaper. Unless you're looking for some kinda personal revenge which I don't think it's worth it.

It's not the end of the world. People are dealing with bad/unreasonable bosses all day long as part of their jobs. Your issue is just a misunderstanding, try to solve it by talking.

Comment: "explain that I was not looking for a job recently (if that's true)" - that's a tough nut to crack if the CV is up to date.

Comment: Good point. I am under the impression that s/he was not looking for a job recently. As recruiters do not contact the candidate each time and ask if they want to apply for the X company? what about Y company? They just apply unless the candidate excludes a few beforehand.

Comment: Well, I keep my CV up to date all the time, whether or not I am even looking. There's usually so many different tasks at work that it would be hard to remember all of them if you'd need to. At least in software development. Just in my current job alone, I've used five different languages and six different frameworks!

Answer (score 1):

Keep on job searching. Speed it up.

Is it really worth sueing? It will cost you a lot, take time and energy and is risky.

Spread what did happen to you to your social network, glassdoor etc.